# Symfony route not found but existing in debugger route result

Tags: php, symfony

I generated a bundle but I receive error trying to access url http://localhost/app_dev.php/event:

```
No route found for "GET /event"
```

then I debugged the router with debug:router, and the router seems to be fine:

```
event_homepage             ANY        ANY      ANY    

/hello/{firstName}/{count}         
event_index                GET        ANY      ANY    /event/                            
event_show                 GET        ANY      ANY    /event/{id}/show                   
event_new                  GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /event/new                         
event_edit                 GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /event/{id}/edit                   
event_delete               DELETE     ANY      ANY    /event/{id}/delete
```

after I have created the bundle automatically I had this error:

```
[ERROR] The bundle's "Resources/config/routing.yml" file cannot be imp
orted
from "app/config/routing.yml" because the "EventBundle" bundle is
already imported. Make sure you are not using two different
configuration/routing formats in the same bundle because it won't work
```

Below is all the routing structure files:

/home/stefano/starwarsevents/app/config/routing.yml

```
event:
resource: "@EventBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

/home/stefano/starwarsevents/src/EventBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
event_homepage:
path:     /hello/{firstName}/{count}
defaults: { _controller: EventBundle:Default:index }

event_event:
resource: "@EventBundle/Resources/config/routing/event.yml"
prefix:   /event
```

/home/stefano/starwarsevents/src/EventBundle/Resources/config/routing/event.yml

```
event_index:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:index" }
methods:  GET

event_show:
path:     /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:show" }
methods:  GET

event_new:
path:     /new
defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:new" }
methods:  [GET, POST]

event_edit:
path:     /{id}/edit
defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:edit" }
methods:  [GET, POST]

event_delete:
path:     /{id}/delete
defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:delete" }
methods:  DELETE
```

Comment: there could be a conflict between `/event/` and   `/event/{id}/show` . Try disabling the second one (or even all the others), and see if you get any positive results (first).

Comment: I tried but nothing . . . I edited this post and added all the routing structure ,I really don't know what is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Slashes are counted and required. To help with this, I've put this [RedirectingController](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html) in my codebase as a (nearly) final route, to catch and redirect to the slash-less version, should it happen.

But in the meantime the URL is currently `/event/`, not `/event`. You could also put the alternate one in as an alternate route to the same place.

Comment: I edited this post and added all the routing structure ,I really don't know what is wrong here

Comment: ossibly re-order the routing file, to make the most generic path/route (`event_index`) at the end.

Comment: Tried but No route found for "GET /event/. That's unbelievable.

Comment: It is working but only in the built in server, on apache don't.

Comment: then check your Apache virtual host settings and rules.